# Ruby on rails Database setup using scaffold generator or Manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

*I am new user to ruby on rails. I have some question please give the answer as early as possible*

**What is the Best way to Create a Database For Your Projects in Rails?**

> 1.Scaffold generator
>
> 2.Manually Design Database​

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Rails then create a project using `rails new project_name` then `cd project_name` then run `rake db:create` it will create a database.

You can modify `database` name like by default rails uses a database e.g `name_development` or `name_production` you can modify this on go to `project/config/database.yml`.

The `rails new project_name` command creates default database adapter e.g `sqlite3` you can define this which adapter he use by default while rails project create.

The `sqlite` is a development database you should change database adapter while going to production like `postgresql` or `mysql` or `mongodb`...

If you need to use `mysql` by default then run below command

```
rails new project_name -d mysql
```

If you need to use `postgresql` by default then  run below command

```
rails new project_name -d postgres
```

It will create a database adapter by default which you need.

***Note:*** You can use both for a command like `rake new project_name` or `rails new project_name`

You need to the read the [`Rails Guides`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) carefully for understand basic Rails. This tutorial assumes you have basic Rails knowledge.

Also here are the [`Rails Commands`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

> Ruby on rails Database setup using scaffold generator or Manually

The scaffold works after create a database.

You can see the [active record basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)  and for basic association you can see the [Michael Hartley tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) this is good tutorial for new RoR programmer.

After all you need to design manually using `reference` or defining by `index` foreign key

Answer (score 0):

First of all decide what kind of database are you going to use. (Msql2 or Postgres are mostly used)

Then design the schema on a paper or anywhere else.

And whenever you're sure. Now everything comes down to 2 different things.

1. You want things to be created automatically. for example: Views, CRUD for database operations in controllers.
2. You want to control things on your own. Now create model from rails commands, write associations, and begin writing your code and define routes as well.

NOTE: Point 2 is implemented when you're going to create a custom application and you may need operations other than basic crud.

Now, you can tell us. What actually you want to achieve and people will help you.